# WPF - How to change language property of a window dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, globalization

I have a window in application that is used to purchase products.Now there r two options Local or Foreign.If a user clicks on local the currency that is ,string format of my textbox holding Rate and Amount should have euros as currency and if user selects foreign it should be dollar.

Window_Purchase.Language = ?

Window_Purchase is the name of my window.

How can I change the language property at runtime.I don't want to change text language only the currency format .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 or more resource files, for example:

(They need to be added under `Properties` in *Solution Explorer*)

Resources.resx
[image]

Resources.de.resx
[image]

They can be dynamically switched with by implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) the following class.

```
namespace WpfApplication1.Properties
{
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using Properties;

    public class ResourceService : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region singleton members

        private static readonly ResourceService _current = new ResourceService();
        public static ResourceService Current
        {
            get { return _current; }
        }
        #endregion

        readonly Properties.Resources _resources = new Properties.Resources();

        public Properties.Resources Resources
        {
            get { return this._resources; }
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion

        public void ChangeCulture(string name)
        {
            Resources.Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(name);
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Resources");
        }
    }
}
```

and the text (currency) you want to change has to bind this to receive `PropertyChanged` event like this:

```
<!-- Add xmlns:properties-->
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Properties">

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:ResourceService.Current}, Path=Resources.Currency, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Then, you can change the `Culture`(`Resources`) dynamically. 

For example:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ResourceService.Current.ChangeCulture("de");
}
```

Comment: How did u add € in string value of resource file ?

Comment: @user5552042 just copied and pasted it.

Answer (score 0):

If i get right you wan't to change the culture info on application?

```
Application.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.GetCultureInfo("en-us");
```

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com)

Comment: No I just want it for a particular window not needed for the whole application

Comment: I tried your given code .the application class does not have any CurrentCulture property

Answer (score 0):

Try this instend for the current form

```
System.Windows.FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(  
                typeof( System.Windows.FrameworkElement ),  
                new System.Windows.FrameworkPropertyMetadata(  
                    System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage( System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag ) ) );
```